# Which private key format is this?

Tags: wallet

I have a paper wallet as an image file, the QR code of the private key gives a base64 encoded string which gives "Salted_(some binary here)" when decoded. What format is this and can I get the private key without a webcam or phone?

Comment: Hi Dorian, welcome to StackExchange. While I'm sure monetary rewards for answers make a great incentive, it isn't something that's allowed here. The reasons are more legal and regulatory than ethical but sadly the fact remains that we can't allow the offering (or requesting) of rewards in questions and answers. Sorry. The good news is you'll probably have no difficulty finding someone here who will help you just because that's what they do. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1):

Probably encrypted using an OpenSSL-interoperable format. See

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8776/what-is-u2fsdgvkx1/8777#8777

http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pbe.html

The 8 bytes following "Salted_" should be the salt.

Example cmdline to decrypt:

```
echo 'U2FsdGVkX19qplb9qVDVVEYxH8wjJDGpMS+F4/2pS2c=' | openssl enc -a -d -salt -des3 -pass pass:changeit
Hello World!
```